# Computing intermediate gradients using backward method in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I am having trouble in understanding `backward` method in pytorch

```
x1 = tensor(2.).requires_grad_()
x2 = tensor(3.).requires_grad_() # or x2 = tensor(3.)
x3 = x1 + x2

l = (x3**2).sum()
l.backward()

print(x1)
print(x3)
print(x1.grad)
print(x3.grad)
```

Results are

```
tensor(2., requires_grad=True)
tensor(5., grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)
tensor(10.)
None
```

Why is `x3.grad` still `None`? Shouldn't it be `tensor(10.)` ?

When I run the following lines of code, `x3.grad` is evaluated to `tensor(10.)`

```
x3 = tensor(5.).requires_grad_()
l = (x3**2).mean()
l.backward()
print(x3.grad)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you print `x3.grad` on your first example you might notice torch outputs a warning:

> UserWarning: The `.grad` attribute of a **Tensor that is not a leaf Tensor is being accessed. Its `.grad` attribute won't be populated during `autograd.backward()`**. If you indeed want the gradient for a non-leaf Tensor, use `.retain_grad()` on the non-leaf Tensor. If you access the non-leaf Tensor by mistake, make sure you access the leaf Tensor instead. See [here](http://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/30531) for more informations.

To save memory the gradients of the non-leaf tensors (non user-created tensors) are not buffered.

If you wish to see those gradients though you can retain the gradient on `x3` by calling `.retain_grad()` before creating the graph (i.e. before calling `.backward()`.

```
x3.retain_grad()
l.backward()
print(x3.grad)
```

will indeed output `tensor(10.)`

Comment: Thanks @Ivan. What does it mean to be a non-leaf (or non user-created) tensor ?

Comment: *user-created* as in not literally defined (like `x1` and `x2` are). See, `x3` is non-leaf because it depends on other tensors in the graph. In the backward pass, the *flow* will first run through `l` then `x3` and finally find `x1` and `x2`, the two leaves of your graph.

Comment: I think I got it. Even though pytorch used x3 in the computational graph, it didn't save the gradients on intermediate nodes to save memory. Thanks a lot @Ivan